# "airmon-ng start wlan0" will not create mon0

Tags: realtek, aircrack-ng, packet-analyzer

I have aircrack-ng 1.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 and whenever I use the command "airmon-ng start wlan0", it always says "monitor mode enabled" instead of "monitor mode enabled on mon0". I checked ifconfig and iwconfig to see if it made another interface name. I have a Realtek RTL8187SE driver. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You need to give us more information if you really want this bounty to work. Can you please give us the output of the command `airmon-ng start wlan0; lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` and your version of `airmon`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify what channel you want your wireless card to operate on while in monitor mode.

Your command should read 
    `airmon-ng start wlan0 wireless-channel 1 to 11`

For example `airmon-ng start wlan0 11` will put your wireless card in monitor mode on channel 11.

For more information check out the man page for airmon-ng

http://linux.die.net/man/1/airmon-ng

Comment: @kprovost7314  How'd it go?

Comment: I figured out that wlan0 was in monitor mode but I do have another problem.

Comment: @kprovost7314 Whats the other issue?

Comment: WEP packet capturing wont make data for cracking.